# How can I tell the progress of a VLC MediaListPlayer?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, vlc, libvlc

I have a Raspberry Pi 3b that I'm using to play music. When a button (GPIO) is pressed, I want to play a list of songs. I'm doing this using the vlc media list player. I build a media list by grabbing N random mp3 files from a directory.

eg:

```
i=vlc.Instance()
l=i.media_list_new()
l.insert_media(i.media_new(...)) # this loops and grabs random mp3s
p=i.media_list_player_new()
p.set_media_list(l)
p.play()
```

Another GPIO signal will call p.stop(). What I want to know at that point is which songs in the media list have been played. This way I can track them and not play them again the next time the Play button is pressed, but the unplayed tracks in the list should still be eligible to play.

So far I don't see any way to get any info from the media list player on what item in the list it's on or another way to tell what has been played from the list.

I tried an alternative of manually looping through a list of songs and using a regular player (not list player), but when I do this I have to do a `while True` loop to make the player wait for one song to finish before playing the next one. This loop also seems to block my GPIO event handler for some reason and pressing the STOP button goes undetected (have to cancel the script to stop).

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be: Don't use the `MediaListPlayer`.

Use a `MediaList` along with a `MediaPlayer` and listen for `libvlc_MediaListEndReached` https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc.html

> loop to make the player wait for one song to finish before playing the next one

Use libvlc events.

Answer (score 0):

Actually got this working using the MediaListPlayer and events. I added an event handler for MediaListPlayerNextItemSet that calls a function that increments a counter, so I know how many songs in the list were played now.